# Can't get the \nomencl package to produce a line break in \elsarticle template

Tags: line, nomencl

I'm trying to separate Greek symbols with Subscripts in my Nomenclature which is created using `nomencl` package with `[intoc]` option on. after using following code I got the nomenclature but greek symbols and subscripts were not separated (by a break line)...

```
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{\item[{{Greek symbols}}]}{
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[{{Subscripts}}]}{}}
}
```

so to seperate Greek symbols and Subscripts from their preceding symbols i tried the following code but I'm getting an unwanted space in my first line... any idea how i can fix this?

```
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\item[]\hspace*{-\leftmargin}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{\item[{{Greek symbols}}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[{{Subscripts}}]}{}}
}
```

and this is how my nomenclature is written...

```
\begin{table*}[!t]
\begin{framed}
\printnomenclature
\end{framed}
\end{table*}
\nomenclature[01]{$C_p$}{specific heat}
.
.
.
\nomenclature[g1]{$\alpha$}{ratio}
.
.
.
\nomenclature[s]{$f$}{fluid}
.
.
.
```

Comment: Welcome! Do you really want the nomenclature in a table? It doesn't make much sense, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @egreg... In fact i'm creating this nomenclature for a manuscript I'm submitting to one of elsevier journals and it's in the template of [elsarticle], so i need to do it in a table